# PHP & MySql and Ajax auto-suggest issue

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap for website. I include Ajax, css and PHP to show Auto Suggestions for mp3 search. Everything is working fine but an issue happened. I tried with different way but the issue is still there.

### The Issue

When type keyword it show suggestion. (OK)

[image]

When you click on keyword from suggestion it works. (OK)

But **when we erase keyword and click on anywhere at page then page content reload and shown as u can see in picture**.
[image]

**Url of website is [http://www.4songs.pk](http://www.4songs.pk/)**

Code in header

```
<script src="http://www.4songs.pk/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){

        $(document).on( 'scroll', function(){

            if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('.scroll-top-wrapper').addClass('show');
            } else {
                $('.scroll-top-wrapper').removeClass('show');
            }
        });

        $('.scroll-top-wrapper').on('click', scrollToTop);
    });

    function scrollToTop() {
        verticalOffset = typeof(verticalOffset) != 'undefined' ? verticalOffset : 0;
        element = $('body');
        offset = element.offset();
        offsetTop = offset.top;
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: offsetTop}, 500, 'linear');
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myAjax = ajax();
function ajax() {
        var ajax = null;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                try {
                        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                catch(e) {}
        }
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                try {
                        ajax = new ActiveXObject("Msxm12.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch (e){
                        try{
                                ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        }
                        catch (e) {}
                }
        }
        return ajax;
}
function request(str) {
    //Don't forget to modify the path according to your theme
        myAjax.open("POST", "/suggestions", true);
        myAjax.onreadystatechange = result;
        myAjax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        myAjax.setRequestHeader("Content-length", str .length);
        myAjax.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        myAjax.send("search="+str);
}
function result() {
        if (myAjax.readyState == 4) {
                var liste = myAjax.responseText;
                var cible = document.getElementById('tag_update').innerHTML = liste;
                document.getElementById('tag_update').style.display = "block";
        }
}
function selected(choice){
        var cible = document.getElementById('s');
        cible.value = choice;
        document.getElementById('tag_update').style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

### The 2nd issue

When auto suggestions load it also include some empty  tags as you can see in picture
I take this picture as doing Inspect Elements
[image]

PHP Code are clean

```
<?php
include('config.php');
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $q = $_POST['search'];
    $sql_res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dump_songs WHERE (song_name LIKE '%$q%') OR (CONCAT(song_name) LIKE '%$q%') LIMIT 10");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_res))
    {?>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="selected(this.innerHTML);"><?=$row['song_name'];?></li>
<?php
    }
}?>
```

Comment: in `<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="selected(this.innerHTML);"><?=$row['song_name'];?></li>` you forget to close the `a` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `function request(str)` put an `if` statement to check if `str` length is greater than zero.

```
function request(str) {
    if(str.length > 0)
    {
        // Your existing code
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('tag_update').innerHTML = '';
    }
}
```

In short words the problem you are describing is happping because the `str` parameter in the data that you send to `/suggestions` is empty. The server returns `304` error which causes a redirect to the root page. Your js script places the returned html into the suggestion container. And thats why you are seeing this strange view.

**-UPDATE 1-**

Added the following code after user request in comments

```
else
{
    document.getElementById('tag_update').innerHTML = '';
}
```

**-UPDATE 2-** (16/07/2014)
In order to handle the second issue (after the user updated his question)

Υou forgot to close the `a` tag in this line of code

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="selected(this.innerHTML);"><?=$row['song_name'];?></li>
```

Comment: Hello Athafoud, Thanks for your great reply. I have applied your solution but now suggestions are not loading can you have a look here http://www.4songs.pk
You can view source code to see your solution on line number 63

Comment: @DJMHA i have a typo, the correct is `length`. sorry!

Comment: Thanks @Athafoud Its working now. One thing need to fix now sir.

When I erase the keyword the suggestion div still appear how can we hide it?